# Extends Seems to not be occuring

Tags: java, compiler-errors, subclass, extends, superclass

As part of my assignment for my class I'm have to maunally copy code from my text book into jgrasp.

I just finished copying the latest assignment, and I checked that I copied it perfectly, code down below. But when I try to compile it I get the following error.

```
FinalExam.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
      setScore(numericScore); 
      ^
  symbol:   method setScore(double)
  location: class FinalExam
1 error
```

I wrote the setScore method in the GradedActivity class so the FinalExam class should have inherited it, the only idea I can think of to explain the error is that it didn't inherit for some reason? Does anyone have an idea or suggestion for why it isn't working?

```
public class GradedActivity
{
   private double score;
   
   public GradedActivity()
   {
      score = 0.0;
   }
   
   private void setScore(double s)
   {
      score = s;
   }
   
   public double getScore()
   {
      return score;
   }
   
   public char getGrade()
   {
      char letterGrade;
      
      if (score >= 90)
         {
            letterGrade = 'A';
         }
      else if (score >= 80)
         {
            letterGrade = 'B';
         }
      else if (score >= 70)
         {
            letterGrade = 'C';
         }
      else if (score >= 60)
         {
            letterGrade = 'D';
         }
      else
         {
            letterGrade = 'F';
         }
         
      return letterGrade;
   }
}
```

```
/**   
   This class determines the grade for a final exam.   
*/
public class FinalExam extends GradedActivity
{
   private int numQuestions;  // Number of questions
   private int numMissed;     // Questions missed
   
   public FinalExam(int questions, int missed)
   {
      double numericScore;
      
      numQuestions = questions;
      numMissed = missed;
      
      numericScore = 100.0 - (missed * getPointsEach());
      
      // Call the inherited setScore method to   
      // set the numeric score.
      setScore(numericScore); 
   }
   
   public int getNumQuestions()
   {
      return numQuestions;
   }
   
   public int getNumMissed()
   {
      return numMissed;
   }
   
   public double getPointsEach()
   {
      return 100.0 / numQuestions;
   }
}
```

Comment: Too much code. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `setScore` is `private`. `FinalExam` can't access it.

Answer (score 1):

`private` functions are **not** inherited. Change

```
private void setScore(double s)
```

to

```
protected void setScore(double s)
```

Comment: Oh thanks. No idea why that's set to private, I must have mistyped something.